# Set Up Test Asterisk Server

Tags: sip, asterisk, pbx

I am working on a project with SIP/IAX functionality and need to set up an Asterisk server just to play with for testing.  Is it possible to set something up so I can have a virtual Asterisk sever as an acting PBX so I can play?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can't imagine it's that difficult, but I haven't had much luck finding anything that takes me from start to finish.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at PBX in a Flash (http://pbxinaflash.net).  They have ISO images to download that will get you going.